# using Microsoft Translate ( GetTranslation Service )

Tags: c#, asp.net, translate

I'm going to build website that uses the translation service from Microsoft. I need to get all the available translations for each word but the code I have provides only one translation while it is supposed to give all available translations. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using microsofttranslator;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel;
using TranslatorService;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{string Appid="my Appid";
string t="any text";
     microsofttranslator.TranslateOptions options = new      microsofttranslator.TranslateOptions();

    options.Category = "general";
        options.ContentType = "text/plain";
        options.User = "TestUserId";
        options.Uri = "";
    bool a=true;
    SoapService s = new SoapService();
    microsofttranslator.GetTranslationsResponse translations = s.GetTranslations(Appid, t, "ar", "en", 5,a, options);
    Response.Write(string.Format("Available translations for source text '{0}' are", t));

    foreach (microsofttranslator.TranslationMatch translationMatch in translations.Translations)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("Translated text: {0}" + Environment.NewLine + " Rating:{1}" + Environment.NewLine + "Count:{2}" + Environment.NewLine, translationMatch.TranslatedText, translationMatch.Rating.ToString(), translationMatch.Count.ToString()));

    } }}
```

I added Microsft translate WSDL as a web reference http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Soap.svc?wsdl and I added TranslatorService as a service reference http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Soap.svc

This code works well but as I said it gives only one translation while it is supposed to give all the available translations of a word. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: the API docs say "all available" and not "all possible"... Whether more than one (and how many) translations for a given word/text exists in the MS translation memory is something only MS can answer... I suspect that for texts/languages you tried it only contains one translation...

Comment: @Yahia Yes I know that it says all available and not all possible.. but I tried so many words but it gives only one translation!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the "translateArray" method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512438.aspx